# "You do not need to search for a job - it will find you itself"

Tags: word-choice

> You do not need to search for a job - it will find you **itself**.

Is the *itself* part correct? Should it be replaced with some other word?

Comment: Assuming I understand what you are trying to convey, I think, "*You don't need to search for a job- the job will find you*." reads better.

Answer (score 2):

"on its own" seems better to me.  Leaving off "itself" altogether as suggested in Jim's comment might be more idiomatic however:

```
"Don't X Y, Y will X you."
```

is a pretty common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Or...........To emphasize you could say......all by itself.

You do not need to search for a job - it will find you all by itself.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer appeared in a review site. Do you have any reference/research that can support your answer? I would advise you to take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to see how it works here.